# Trying to include character in my regex without effecting functionality

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the below regex in my HTML

```
pattern='/^[^<>{}]*$/'
```

I want to include this character **'**

But when I include it in the regex string it closes the string.

When I include it I break the close string so it does not count it. Is there a way to escape this character and include it in the regex?

Similar to how you could include **"** characters in a JSON String by doing **\"** see below

"JOSN_STRING" : "Example \"String\"",

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `"` to delimit the pattern attribute instead. (Also note that the `pattern` in HTML should not have `/`s at the beginning or end, nor `^` and `$` anchors.)

```html
<form>
  <input pattern="[^'<>{}]*" value="'">
  <button>click</button>
</form>
```

You can also keep using `'` delimiters and use the `&apos;` HTML entity inside the attribute, but that's much less readable:

```html
<form>
  <input pattern='[^&apos;<>{}]*' value="'">
  <button>click</button>
</form>
```

To exclude both `"` and `'`s, you'll have to use at least one HTML entity:

```html
<form>
  <input pattern='[^"&apos;<>{}]*' value="'">
  <button>click</button>
</form>
```

Comment: &apos; does not seem to be working and if I already include " then I'll have a similar problem, so for the example below, how would I include " and ' in the below regex?

<form>
  <input pattern="[^'<>{}"]*">
  <button>click</button>
</form>

Comment: Works fine here - see the snippets. When `'` is the value, the pattern validation fails. If you want to prevent both quotes, pick one delimiter, and use the HTML entity for that delimiter as well as the other literal quote character